# Why is Django not able to display the correct categories according to tags?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have been stuck on this problem for 2 days. My product is supposed to show categories that match the tag the user has selected. However, whenever I click on a tag, it shows this error message:
Page not found (404)
No category found matching the query
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/tag/class-1
Raised by:  content.views.TagDetail

The TagDetail view:

```
class TagDetail(DetailView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'content/tag_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'categories'

    def get_queryset(self):     
        self.tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])     
        return Category.objects.filter(tag=self.tag).order_by('id')

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):        
        context = super(TagDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        context['tag'] = self.tag
        return context
```

My Tag model:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Tag, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My Category model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, default='book.jpg', upload_to='media')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    brief = models.CharField(max_length=150,default=None)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,related_name='categories',blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def category_tag(self):
        return ', '.join(str(tag) for tag in self.tag.all())
```

Please help me out here!

Comment: The model for your TagDetail view is `Post`? But you pass it a slug for `Tag` though? And somehow in your error you get no matching query for `Category` (even though you don't seem to be using it)?? Can you clarify _what_ exactly is that view for and what model is it for?

Comment: Uh- I think I put the wrong view- I'll just edit it

Comment: It still doesn't make sense now your view is for the model `Category`, you pass it a slug for `Tag` and return a queryset for `Post`?? As I said in the previous comment please clarify what exactly that view is for and what is it supposed to do...

Comment: The TagDetail view is supposed to filter the categories according to the requested tag and display them using tag_detail.html

Answer (score 0):

A `DetailView` is supposed to deal with a *single object*. Here you want to display a *list* of `Category` which are related to a `Tag` instance. What is happening is that the `DetailView` is trying to filter the queryset you return with the slug you meant to pass for the `Tag` but obviously there is no such `Category` giving you an error. What you can do instead is simply keep it as a detail view for `Tag`:

```
class TagDetail(DetailView):
    model = Tag
    template_name = 'content/tag_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'tag'
```

Next in the template you can simply loop over the related `Category` instances like:

```
{% for category in tag.categories.all %}
    {{ category.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

OR you can use a `ListView` for `Category` and override its `get_queryset` to filter based on the `Tag`:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView


class CategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Category
    ordering = 'id'
    template_name = 'content/tag_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'categories'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        self.tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        super().get_queryset().filter(tag=self.tag)
    
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['tag'] = self.tag
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you so very much